# I need to display fields based on the picklist value. When i try to save it, I keep geting field_exception error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:attribute name="toggleNet" type="boolean" default="true" />
            <aura:attribute name="toggleGross" type="boolean" />
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center ">
            <lightning:select name="netselect" aura:id="analysisform" label="Net or Gross" onchange="{!c.toggle}" >
              <option>Net</option>
              <option>Gross</option>
              <option>Gross+Electric</option>
            </lightning:select>
            </div>

     <aura:if isTrue="{!v.toggleNet}">
           <lightning:input aura:id="analysisform" label="Current Year Operating Expenses ($/sf/Yr)"
                             name="currentyearoperatingexpenses"
                             value="{!v.newTestForm.Current_Year_Operating_Expenses_sf_Yr__c}"/> 



        <aura:set attribute="else">

          <aura:if isTrue="{!v.toggleGross}">   
            <lightning:input aura:id="analysisform" label="Expense Stop ($/sf/Yr)"
                             name="expensestop"
                             value="{!v.newTestForm.Expense_Stop_sf_Yr__c}"
                             required="false"/>

            <lightning:input aura:id="analysisform" label="Current Year Operating Expense ($/sf)"
                             name="currentyearoperatingexpensesforgross"
                             value="{!v.newTestForm.Current_Year_Operating_Expense_sf__c}"
                             required="false"/>     

            <aura:set attribute="else">             
            <lightning:input aura:id="analysisform" label="Electricity $/sq ft"
                             name="electricity"
                             value="{!v.newTestForm.Electricity_sq_ft__c}"
                             required="false"/>
            </aura:set>
          </aura:if>
        </aura:set>
   </aura:if>
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please [edit] your question to provide the complete, verbatim text of the error and its line number in the body of your post.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting any option value in select `onchange` handler because you have not mentioned `value` in options. Change the `lightning:select` to below:

```
<lightning:select name="netselect" aura:id="analysisform" label="Net or Gross" onchange="{!c.toggle}" >
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="Net">Net</option>
    <option value="Gross">Gross</option>
    <option value="Gross+Electric">Gross+Electric</option>
</lightning:select>
```

This will return the selected value from option in `toggle` method:

```
toggle : function (component, event, helper) {
    let selected = event.getParam('value');

    // handle logic based on selected
},
```